# Извлечение картинок из excel (.xlsx)

Tags: excel

Есть файл, в нем куча строк, где в первой ячейке каждой строки картинка, во второй ячейке каждой строки название картинки.

Как выгрузить все картинки и назначить им имя из ячейки с названием картинки?

Comment: интересно по какому критерию минусовка производится? По содержимому ? Оно , конешно, приятно, что кто-то читает, но было б приятней получить ответ, а не школьную оценку....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У объекта `ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet` есть свойство `Shapes`.

1. Перебираем все `Shapes` и находим левую верхнюю ячейку (`TopLeftCell`) относительно картинки;
2. Берем содержимое ячеки правее (это будет имя файла);
3. Записываем картинку в файл, например как сказано [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28914587/3349900)

PS. Если в файл вставлены картинки руками, то возможно что они вставлены криво и левый верхний угол будет вылезать в соседний ряд или столбец. Возможны и другие проблемы, которые можно обнаржить только имея в наличии сам файл.

Comment: спасибо за исчерпывающий ответ....к сожалению я надеялся на более легкий путь. И то, что полсле PS это как раз относится к моей задаче. Но зато теперь есть тыл - и это приятная новость.

Comment: Если вылезает в соседний столбец, то тут все просто - игнорируем полученный столбец и указываем правильный. Со строкой хуже. Нужно смотреть по "обстановке". Например если картика есть в каждой строке, то обрабатывать ситуации когда строки пропускаются или оказываются две картинки в строке

Comment: не... ну с дальнейшей логикой я справлюсь, не программно - так ручками (скорее  чужими). для экселя даже ТОРГ12 как в 1с выводил. но за дополнения отдельное спасибо.

Comment: а есть ли рекомендации(примеры) по извлечению картинок написанных на java?

Comment: "картинок написанных на java" это как? Или, из чего извлекать?

Comment: из экселя извлекать, встал вопрос извлечения из множества файлов загржаемых на сервер, причём разной структуры.... как читать знаю, но хотелось бы практических рекомендаций

Comment: Я бы поставил "безголовый" OpenOffice и работал с файлами через UNO. Для UNO много документации и не всегда достаточно примеров, но разобраться можно (и сделать можно практически что угодно). Кстати писать можно не только на Java

Comment: надо автоматизировать , аплоад на сайт инфы из экселя , сервак на java.